# UTF-8 works on Eclipse but fails to work with an exported jar

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, utf-8, jar

I am working on a desktop application with `Java` `Swing` and save data on a `MySQL` database in arabic language with using `UTF-8`.

When I run the application from `Eclipse` everything work well but when I finish and I export my work to a `runnable jar` using `Eclipse` `export`, nothing related to the database works.

- Login doesn't work
- When I try to save date to my database in `Arabic` I get `??????` in the database

However, as I mentioned earlier, everything work correctly when I run it from `Eclipse`. Can any one help me, I must deliver my work

This is a sample of my work:

This is how I connect connect my database :

```
static Connection conn = null;
static String url      = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
static String dbName   = "gestiondestock";
static String driver   = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static String userName = "root"; 
static String password = "";
static String unicode= "?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
```

This is the code for `buttonLogin` `ActionPerformed`:

```
private void buttonLogin_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(textField.getText().equals("") || passwordField.getText().equals(""))
    {
       jd =new JDialog();
        jd.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        jd.setTitle("الرجاء ملء الفراغ");
        jd.setVisible(true);
        jd.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jd.setSize(400,200);
        jd.setContentPane(buildpp());   
    }
    else{
        if(textField.getText().equals("Adel91") || passwordField.getText().equals("Adel91"))
        {
            CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) contentPane.getLayout();
            cardLayout.show(contentPane, "Panel_Home");
        }
        else{
            try{
                String usernamena = new String(textField.getText());
                String passwordlogin = new String(passwordField.getText());

                MessageDigest mdEnc4 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

                mdEnc4.update(passwordlogin.getBytes(), 0, passwordlogin.length());
                String passwordlogindmd5 = new BigInteger(1, mdEnc4.digest()).toString(16); // Encrypted 

                try{
                    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName+unicode,userName,password);
                    Statement st = conn.createStatement();

                    ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT username,password FROM client ");

                    String user = null;
                    String pass = null;

                    if(res.next()) {
                        user = new String( res.getBytes(1), "UTF-8");
                        pass =  new String( res.getBytes(2), "UTF-8");
                    }

                    if(usernamena.equals(user)&&passwordlogindmd5.equals(pass)){
                        CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) contentPane.getLayout();
                        cardLayout.show(contentPane, "Panel_Home");
                    }
                    else{
                        jd =new JDialog();
                        jd.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
                        jd.setTitle("كلمة المرور والإسم غير مناسبان");
                        jd.setVisible(true);
                        jd.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                        jd.setSize(430,200);
                        jd.setContentPane(buildwronglogin());
                    }
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                    ee.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }   
}
```

Resulting MySQL variables using this cmd :SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'c%';
abd every thins is uts8

[image]

Comment: This question is horrid. We need code, errors, anything! Plus it is in need of formating.

Comment: @SLaks when i use the exported jar i cant do the login but when i run it from eclipse i can ,so i removed the login  and i try to save data from the exported jar i find on the data base ?????? but when i run it from eclipse i can save the data

Comment: How do you expect anyone to possibly help you without at the least a snippet of code?

Comment: @veer ok i will edit and add an exemple how im donig it

Comment: @veer any thing wrong on my code ??

Comment: **Do not use MD5**.   You should use a secure, salted, iterated hash.  Preferably scrypt, bcrypt, or PBKDFv2.

Comment: @SLaks when i insert data i dont use MD5 but the seem thing !!

Comment: @SLaks i said when i run it from exlipe every thing work i dont thing the problem is on MD5

Comment: I know the problem is not with MD5.  However, when your database gets hacked, the problem will be with MD5.  _Do not use MD5._

Comment: @Slaks ok thank you about that , but do you have any idea for my problem , plz i need help on this one

Comment: @user1417996: This is off-topic but next time when you post your code, please make sure that it is correctly formatted. Especially when you're posting a considerable size of your code :)

Comment: @Sujay thank you for your help sir , i will be sure next time

Comment: Your logic will fail if you have more than one user.  Use a WHERE clause with parameters.

Comment: @Slaks i have only one user and it work when i run the app from eclipse i want any idea why when i export it on jar file its don't work ??????

Comment: Error message would be usefull, Also are you using the same version of Java when running from Eclipse and standalone. Some charsets are in Charset.jar (rather than runtime.jar). If there is a problem/missing charset.jar in the verson of java use to run the jar you would get this type of issue

Comment: @BruceMartin sir i don't get any Error when i run it from eclipse and i save a data in my database i found the data on the table in ut8 but when i save a data from the jar file i find on the database only ?????????

Comment: Thaaank's for evey one for your help and advice ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should never convert a String to bytes using an unspecified charset (here you are using the platform default, which could change):

```
passwordlogin.getBytes()
```

Since this is for the bytes you are going to hash, which charset you use doesn't really matter as long as it is consistent.  something like `passwordlogin.getBytes("UTF-8")` would seem reasonable.

Also, this is certainly a problematic bit of code:

```
                if(res.next()) {
                    user = new String( res.getBytes(1), "UTF-8");
                    pass =  new String( res.getBytes(2), "UTF-8");
                }
```

it seems to imply that you have a characterset breakdown somewhere.

Lastly, how are you running your jar?  Are you specifying a charset on the command line (e.g. `java -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" ...`).

Comment: if i dont convert  String to bytes using an unspecified charset how i gave to to convert them  because i have to due to mysql

Comment: no sir i'm not specifying a charset on the command line , how to do this ? and thank you for your help

Comment: updated above.  also, i show how to specify the charset in my example command line.

Comment: @jtahlborn: Hi..Can you please draw pointers on this question. At least for UTF part. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059807/utf-encoded-data-works-with-jsp-but-not-when-export-pdf-using-xmlworkerhelper

Answer (score 3):

Launch it with `java -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" -jar JarFile.jar`

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: open terminal and paste this line {change [JarFile.jar] with your path to .jar}

Comment: And without terminal, that means with double click?