# How do I change the encoding of my jar file to manage characters such as "█▓▒ CRIT! ░░╚╡▌▌╞╗░░"?

Tags: java, encoding, jar

*EDITED*

hey guys.

My code is using pircBot to send IRC messages to twitch.tv.

The messages include characters such as '█▓▒ CRIT! ░░╚╡▌▌╞╗░░'

Example output code: sendMessage("#twitchraidstwitch", "/me █▓▒ CRIT! ░░╚╡▌▌╞╗░░");

So These characters originally all displayed as '?' in Eclipse. They didn't work properly until I changed my window -> preferences -> text file encoding to US-ASCII. (Though I've just learned these characters aren't even ASCII.)

When I export my project to a jar and try to run in CMD, the characters are back to '?'.

How do I got about getting this to work in cmd?

Thanks!

Comment: Huh? None of those characters are in ASCII.

Comment: No? What are they UTF-8? The only 'Text file encoding' setting that got those to output correctly in eclipse was ASCII. Still how to I set the encoding to get those characters to show?

Comment: We'll need some reproducible code. Otherwise, we can't even be sure that your problem statement is accurate.

Comment: It's sending messages over IRC using PircBot's 'sendMessage(channel,"█▓▒ CRIT! ░░╚╡▌▌╞╗░░"); The output is correct from eclipse after I set the encoding to ASCII but '?' when running from a JAR. I'm not sure what else to give.

Comment: You should save all your source code as UTF-8. Also, when you encode your text for IRC, make sure you're encoding as UTF-8 too. This is just about the only sane way to get some kind of consistency with non-ASCII characters. http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: I put the setting back to UTF-8 and it still worked from eclipse but not cmd. I'm curious why I was under the impression UTF-8 didn't work before. Am I not saving my source as UTF-8?

Comment: Have you also tried applying the encoding on PircBot's end with its setEncoding method?

Comment: character or letter in this question is not what it is . But still these kind of problem i face.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I got it to work.

I used setEncoding("UTF-8"); as Score_Under suggested. It didn't change anything but it didn't hurt either.

I then launched with java -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" -jar JarFile.jar and that did the trick.

I figured it out from [UTF-8 works on Eclipse but fails to work with an exported jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151027/utf-8-works-on-eclipse-but-fails-to-work-with-an-exported-jar)