# Question mark with diamond when read nvarchar from SQL Server

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

I got a very strange problem here.

I need to read data from SQL Server (ver. 2016). A name like `O'Neal`.

When I load the String in my IDE/TextEditor, `O'Neal` could be read correctly as `O'Neal`.

But when I package my program as jar or war file, `O'Neal` is loaded like this `O��Neal`.

I have no idea how does this happend. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by loaded? Are you trying to print that value somewhere? If the actual text is encoded with UTF-8, make sure you use the same encoding while displaying the text.

Comment: @ShashankKadne Sorry about lack of the info. Yes, I print them in console. Actually, I'm not sure the encoding, I checked `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')`, it returns SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151027/utf-8-works-on-eclipse-but-fails-to-work-with-an-exported-jar)

Like @Arvind said, it runs correctly in IDE/Editor, because it's already encoded as UTF-8.

However, the jar or tomcat isn't, so we have to make sure it runs with encoding UTF-8.

1. In Windows 10 CMD, the jar file could run like this:

`> java -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" -jar test.jar`

However this command couldn't run in PowerShell, I don't know why it's another issue.

2. If you want to run war file on tomcat server, in `{pathToTomcat}/bin`, open `catalina.bat` with editor.

add `set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"`